# Database won't updated using android volley

Tags: android, database, android-volley

I tried to update database on server with calling API by using Google Volley. But somehow the database won't updated. The issue doesn't exist while retrieving data (Method.GET)

Here my snipet code :

```
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(.....);

    JsonObjectRequest postReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Api.URL_POST_DATA, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    progressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (response.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("{\"result\":\"OK\"}")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    postReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    postReq.setShouldCache(false);

    VolleyHelper.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(postReq);
    VolleyHelper.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate(Api.URL_POST_DATA, true);
```

Then i tried update database manually by using PostMan to make sure that the problem not on my API side and my database successfully updated.

Did i doing wrong on my code ? Any helps will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what do you send exactly with the postman

Comment: @djodjo i just sent the http post with all params on the body.

Comment: do you sent Json or params in postman ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Content-Type` value of your request header to "`application/json`". This may be the issue.
In order to do that, you need to override the `getHeaders()` method on your request object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the clue, i did wrong. I sent the HashMap but on my request i sent the JsonObjectRequest. So i used StringObject instead of JsonObjectRequest.